# Copying file from one directory to another directory based on timestamp

Tags: shell, ssh

Need to get the file from one directory to another directory based on the timestamp of the file.

```
/Directory1  - From directory
TEMP-dummy-20160812-1149.200476.xml
TEMP-dummy-20160812-1151.000000.xml
TEMP-dummy-20160812-1152.000000.xml
```

I need to copy the file for which the timestamp greater than **20160812-1150.000000**.

Note:The timestamp **20160812-1150.000000** will be present in one static file.

### The expected result:

```
/Directory2
TEMP-dummy-20160812-1151.000000.xml
TEMP-dummy-20160812-1152.000000.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd /Path/to/Directory1
ref_timestamp=201608121150000000 # punctuation marks deliberately removed.
for file in *
do
  timestamp=$(echo ${file} | cut -c 12-31 | tr -cd [:digit:])
  if [ ${timestamp} -ge ${ref_timestamp} ]
  then
    cp ${file} /Path/to/Directory2
  fi
done
```

This code snippet assumes you are using `tr` from GNU Coreutils, not a stock `tr` which comes with legacy Unix systems, such as Sun Solaris, AIX or HP-UX.

Comment: You have `do` before your `for` loop. You might fix it.

Comment: That `tr` syntax is POSIX so would work with AIX/HP-UX/Solaris... However on Solaris, you'd need to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/tr`, not the one in `/usr/bin`. Here though, you need to quote the `[:digit:]` as that's also a shell glob.

Comment: You also forgot to quote the variables.

Comment: The `[ -ge ]` comparison won't work properly in shells that with work 32 bit integers like `mksh`.

Comment: Thanks MelBurslan and Stephane. The code is working great.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
cd /dir1 &&
  mv TEMP-dummy-*(e:'[[ $REPLY > TEMP-dummy-20160812-1150.000000 ]]':) /dir2
```

POSIXly and assuming all those files follow that pattern:

```
cd /dir1 &&
  printf '%s\n' TEMP-dummy-* |
    awk '$0 > "TEMP-dummy-20160812-1150.000000"' |
    xargs sh -c '[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || exec mv "$@" /dir2' sh
```